# Python String List additions

Tags: python

I currently have a list (array) predefined and I am looking to add information into the array utilizing the split function.  I want to keep the original items in the array.  Here is my sample code:

```
mylist = []
for i in range(10):
    a = 'array%i' %i
    mylist.append(a)

szResult = "blah1 blah2 blah3 blah4"
mylist = szResult.split()
print mylist
```

When i print the output of the list it shows only the blah[1-4].  I was curious how to add this in with retaining it where mylist[4] would be array4

Comment: The code you have posted is not valid python.

Comment: looks like it..nope...its just me learning how python works.

Comment: in python, it is not socially acceptable to use the Hungarian Notation (szResult), and also most don't use CamelCase, instead they prefer underscores and lower caps. Here is a [link](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to the official style guide PEP8. You better start getting used to this style early :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use slice assignment:

```
mylist[:4] = szResult.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
mylist = szResult.split()
```

to

```
result = szResult.split()
mylist = result + mylist[len(result):]
```

or

```
result = szResult.split()
mylist[:len(result)] = result
```

Comment: ok..this adds it to the end of the array.  i wanted blah1 to replace the first part of the array etc.

Comment: so the end result would be mylist[0] = blah1 , mylist[1]= blah2....mylist[4] = array4

Comment: The two are not equivalent, extend is in place, and += will actually create a new List instance.